# spread operator giving error in react js , saying unexpected token

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am fetching an api in react and then mapping them to make a component.I am using spread operator to edit a particular attribute of the object which is stored in a array.But as soon as I write the onClick function,it gives me error.Otherwise everything is correct.The problem is in the onClick function of the svg.problem starts when i give 'value.quantity' and ,

Errors : The parser expected to find a '}' to match the '{' token here.,
Unexpected token. Did you mean `{'}'}` or `&rbrace;`?,
Expected corresponding JSX closing tag for 'div'.,
Declaration or statement expected.,
Declaration or statement expected.

```
let Cart = () => {

    let [myItems, setMyItems] = useState([])

    let fetchData = () => {
        fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/get-order-item/' + sessionStorage.getItem('id'), {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Authorization': 'Bearer' + ' ' + sessionStorage.getItem('token')
            }
        }).then(
            (response) => {
                return response.json()
            }
        ).then(
            (data) => {
                if (data) {
                    setMyItems(data)
                }
            })
    }

    useEffect(
        () => {
            fetchData()
            console.log(myItems)
        }, []
    )


    return (
        <div>
            {
                myItems.map(
                    (value) => {
                        return (
                            <div className='row  w-100 m-auto' >
                                <div className="card-deck container-fluid m-auto bg-light">
                                    <div className="card  bg-light mt-4 mb-2 " >
                                        <img src={value.item.image} className="card-img-top" alt="..." />
                                        <div className="card-body border-top ">
                                            <div className='d-flex justify-content-between' >
                                                <h4>{value.item.title}</h4>
                                                <div className='d-flex flex-row-reverse' >                                      
                                                    <svg onClick = { () => { setMyItems( { ...myItems , value.quantity : 1 }) } } id='add' xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="28" height="23" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-plus" viewBox="0 0 16 16" >
                                                        <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M8 4a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v3h3a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1h-3v3a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0v-3h-3a.5.5 0 0 1 0-1h3v-3A.5.5 0 0 1 8 4z" />
                                                    </svg>
                                                <input defaultValue={value.quantity} className='w-25 h-75 text-center' />
                                                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="32" height="25" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-dash" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                                                    <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M4 8a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h7a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1h-7A.5.5 0 0 1 4 8z" />
                                                </svg>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <h5>{value.item.price}</h5>
                                        <div class="form-check d-flex  justify-content-between">
                                            <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="quantity" checked={value.ordered} />
                                            <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleCheck1">Proceed this item to checkout</label>
                                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success ">Save changes</button>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            </div>
    )
}
                )
            }
        </div >
    )


}

export default Cart;
```

Comment: You should include the error it gives you

Comment: How do I add errors?it is giving me 17 errors

Comment: One this I can see is that the initial state to items is an array, not an object, like whats passed in

Comment: Copy and paste the error that you're talking about into the question

Comment: Objects are passed in the array

Comment: ',' expected.This is the error

Comment: No that's no happening. You're passing in an object, not an array

Comment: Copy and paste the whole error and edit the question to include it

Comment: Your initial state is an array, but when you set the state, you change it to an object.

Comment: i tried but didnt worked

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
{ setMyItems( { ...myItems , value.quantity : 1 }) }
```

I believe it should be :

you have to destructure an array not an object since it's your initial value

```
{ setMyItems( [...myItems , { value: { quantity : 1 } } ]) }
```

Comment: I am using a map function so the quantity should be value.quantity

Comment: I wrote your code but as soon as i changed it to value.quantity its throwing me error.Before that everythink was fine

Comment: you cannot do that you have to specify the static key... or you can do [value.quantity]

Comment: Its not showing any error on terminal but as soon as I click it ,it is showing cannot read value of image undefined

Answer (score -1):

```
<svg onClick={() => setMyItems({ value: { quantity: 1 }, ...myItems })} id='add' xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="28" height="23" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-plus" viewBox="0 0 16 16" ></svg>
```

Comment: different error or same? the `value.quantity : 1` part is probably wrong - probably needs to just be `value: 1` or `{ quantity: 1 }`. Hard to know without knowing more about your app.

Comment: or `{ value: { quantity: 1 } }`

Comment: have updated my answer with something to try

Comment: Showing that it's not a function in the map